# What does the option Method->Method in NIntegrate mean?

Tags: options, numerical-integration

Among options for `NIntegrate` one finds the following construction `Method->{name1, Method->name2}`. For example, `Method -> {"EvenOddSubdivision", Method -> "LocalAdaptive"}`. It seems that both "EvenOddSubdivision" and "LocalAdaptive" can be used as the integration methods. Then the question arises, what does their combination mean?

I failed to find an explanation what means the second Method here.

I would like to understand, how to find out, what methods could be combined together this way. For example, can one combine like `Method -> {"EvenOddSubdivision", Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"}`?

Comment: As far as i can tell, the second `Method` is a submethod of the first. If Mathematica really accepts these settings (and does really different things) then this means that you can have `"EvenOddSubdivision"` with `"LocalAdaptive"` and `"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"` as strategies for subdivision. Other methods than ``"EvenOddSubdivision"` might not support the same subobtions. At least that is how it works for the `Methods` of `LinearSolve`, `FindRoot`, and `FindMinimum` with which I am more familiar. However, I cannot tell what the precise meaning of these combinations is.

Comment: Some of this is explained in the tutorial "Advanced Numerical Integration in the Wolfram Language". See tutorial/NIntegrateOverview in the Documentation Center.

Comment: There's `Method -> { strategy, Method -> rule }` and some strategies, can be nested such as preprocessors like `"EvenOddSubdivision"`: `Method -> {"EvenOddSubdivision", Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", Method -> {"ClenshawCurtisRule"}}}`.